# How to generate bitmap from 2 bitmaps?

Tags: java, image, opengl-es, triangulation, delaunay

Let take a look at this image: the left is frame 5 while the right is frame 0

[image]

Click here is you want to view the higher resolution of [frame 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YhoJ.jpg) or [frame 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBvyz.jpg)

Frame 0 means there is no rotation while frame 5 means it's rotated 5 degrees from frame 0.

In each frame, there is a list of edge (2D) from delaunay triangulation (which is displayed as a mesh as you see).

I also have list of edge (2D) from delaunay triangulation for frame 1 (rotate 1 degree from frame 0), frame 2, frame 3, frame 4.

With these parameter, could anyone tell me how to generate image (bitmap) of frame 1, 2, 3,4 so that when scroll from frame 0 to frame 5, it looks smooth.

Any help would be appreciated.

--

Answer (score 1):

I already answered your question on Google+ but I think it is a good idea to also post the answer right here for other people who will come up with a similar problem.

The thing which is needed here is called 'optical flow'. There is a huge amount of information on the web about this topic but I want you to refere you to one lecture I visited in university: 
http://www.gris.tu-darmstadt.de/teaching/courses/ss11/cv1/index.en.htm

The slides 'motion estimation' will give you a quick starting point about this topic but you definitely have to read additional literature. One of the literature mentioned on the course's website is available as free pdf and covers most of the basic understandings of computer vision.

What you are trying to achieve will be difficult but absolutely possible.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Hahn. I'm agree with you it's really difficult, but at least I now should focus on `Optical flow`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linear transformation from the mesh. You can take the start and endpoint and use straight lines and multiple from the frames for the transformation. It uses in simple 3d animations and morphing.